# Server error on microsoft Video Indexer

Tags: azure, video, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use Video Indexer but keep getting the following error, spelling typo and all:
"Faild indexing video Please delete or re-index playlist"

There is also an orange/red "server error" message box that pops up at the bottom right of the screen if i try to re-index the video.

The video seems to upload properly and begins processing but fails at 5% with the error above. I get the error regardless of if i use a URL to a video stored in a cloud service or directly from my hard drive.

I have the same problem with multiple accounts and Azure subscriptions.

I have used Indexer in the past with no problems.

Any ideas on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a member of the [video indexer](https://vi.microsoft.com/) development team.

We are currently working on improving the upload experience in [video indexer](https://vi.microsoft.com/) It should be released in the next couple of days.

If you could share more info about your specific request by sending video name, account name to *visupport@microsoft.com* (please include a reference to this question).

I will check and see what is the root cause and share the resolution with the rest of stackoverflow community.

Comment: @lka was there a resolution? I am seeing this behavior for videos from YouTube and Vimeo using both the URL and downloading as submitting for indexing.

Comment: Video Indexer does not allow direct links from YouTube.